# I want to Passing a image from Drawable from one activity to Another via Intent?

Tags: android

I am using this part of code to send the image...

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent goto_membersdealsdetails = new Intent(
                        "com.abc.cd.FE");

                goto_membersdealsdetails.putExtra("valueq", R.drawable.app_icon);


                v.getContext().startActivity(goto_membersdealsdetails);
```

And to get the image i am using this sort of code...

```
   imag_link = getIntent().getStringExtra("valueq");

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imag_link, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
```

Its Toast is providing a blank toast....

I want to set the image to a certain imageview....Suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an int value in intent. so call

```
imag_link = getIntent().getIntExtra("valueq", value);
```

Comment: This Worked   :      int imag_link = getIntent().getIntExtra("valueq", R.drawable.bar_normal);

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imag_link, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();

Answer (score 2):

you can pass byte array and get bytearray and then make bitmap

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);     
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("picture", b);
    startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity B you receive intent with byte array (decoded picture) and apply it as source to ImageView:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```